# Выполнение функции в отдельном потоке java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть такой код, в котором надо функцию запустить отдельным потоком. Нужно передать этой функции строку и получить ответ. Как это сделать?

```
public class Main {

    //функция, которую нужно выполнить в отдельном потоке
    public static String executePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters) {}

    static class SomeThing implements Runnable  
    {
        public void run()   
        {
            System.out.println("Привет из побочного потока!");
        }
    }

    private static SomeThing mThing;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mThing = new SomeThing();
        Thread myThready = new Thread(mThing);
        myThready.start();

        //так это работает в основном потоке
        String forSearch = "Radioactive";
        String quest = executePost("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" + forSearch, "");
    }
 }
```

Comment: А что вы хотите делать с ответом, полученным от этой функции, в основном потоке?

Comment: парсить его, парсер уже готов

Comment: А чем основной поток будет заниматься, пока в дополнительном потоке формируется ответ? И как должен узнать, что в дополнительном готов результат? Вы продумывали как это всё будет работать?

Comment: ждать результата. как? я хз, буду разбираться

Comment: Вот это ключевой момент: если основной поток будет просто ждать и ничего не делать всё это время, то тогда нет смысла заводить отдельный поток: можно всё делать в основном.

Comment: мне дали задание, сделать поиск по itunes store, эта функция будет отправлять запрос и принимать ответ, потом это парсится и выводится необходимое на скрол вью. Доп задачами является сделать запрос асинхронно и загрузить картинку асинхронно, но это потом сам разберусь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться классами `Callable` и `FutureTask`:

```
public class Main {

    //функция, которую нужно выполнить в отдельном потоке
    public static String executePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters) { return "any";}

    static class SomeThing implements Callable<String>
    {
        String targetURL;
        String urlParameters;

        SomeThing(String url, String params) {
            this.targetURL = url;
            this.urlParameters = params;
        }

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Привет из побочного потока!");
            return executePost(targetURL, urlParameters);
        }
    }

    private static SomeThing mThing;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String forSearch = "Radioactive";
        mThing = new SomeThing("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" + forSearch, "");

        FutureTask<String> task = new FutureTask<>(mThing);
        Thread myThready = new Thread(task);
        myThready.start();

        try {
            String quest = task.get();
            System.out.println(quest);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            //something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я ведь правильно понимаю, что основной поток зависнет на `task.get` до окончания работы дополнительного? В чём тогда преимущество от использования отдельного потока?

Comment: Все правильно. В данном случае и нет никакого преимущества, потому что у вас основной поток не занят ничем, пока ждет ответа

Comment: Может, доработать пример в ответе, чтобы от использования `FutureTask` был толк? Сделать что-нибудь в духе цикла с проверкой методом `isDone`.

Comment: @Regent на самом деле я бы все тут переделал. Но я только внес правки в код автора, не переписывая всё целиком, чтобы ему было легче разобраться. Потому что вопрос был в том, как сделать, чтобы его метод поработал в другом потоке и отдал результат в основной. А так я тут вообще не вижу смысла в многопоточности

Comment: Хорошо, пусть автор сам решает. В конце концов, ваш код делает то, что и требовалось.

Answer (score 0):

Окончание стека потока можно отследить с помощью wait() и notifyAll():

```
public class Main {

//функция, которую нужно выполнить в отдельном потоке
    public static String executePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters) {
        //...
    }

    static class SomeThing implements Runnable {

        private Object holder;
        private static String result;
        private String targetURL;
        private String urlParameters;

        public SomeThing(Object holder, String targetURL, String urlParameters) {
            this.holder = holder;
            this.targetURL = targetURL;
            this.urlParameters = urlParameters;
        }
        public void run() {
            synchronized (holder) {
                result = executePost(targetURL, urlParameters);
                holder.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        public String getResult() {
            return result;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Object holder = new Object();
        String forSearch = "Radioactive";
        SomeThing mThing = new SomeThing(holder, "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" + forSearch, "");
        Thread myThready = new Thread(mThing);
        myThready.start();
        synchronized (holder) {
            holder.wait();
        }
        String result = SomeThing.result;
        //...

    }
}
```

Comment: Этот код не сработает, если потоков будет больше, чем 1

Comment: Никто не говорил о потоках больше чем 1, кроме того никто не мешает на каждый поток вешать новый монитор ;)